nvcc is not installed despite successfully running conda install command
I followed following steps to setup conda environment with python 3.8, CUDA 11.8 and pytorch 2.4.1:
$ conda create -n py38_torch241_CUDA118 python=3.8
$ conda activate py38_torch241_CUDA118
$ conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.8 -c pytorch -c nvidia

Python and pytorch seem to have installed correctly:
$ python --version
Python 3.8.20

$ pip list | grep torch
torch               2.4.1
torchaudio          2.4.1
torchvision         0.20.0

But when I try to check CUDA version, I realise that nvcc is not installed:
$ nvcc
Command 'nvcc' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit

This also caused issue in the further setup of some git repositories which require nvcc. Do I need to run sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit as suggested above? Shouldnt above conda install command install nvcc? I tried these steps again by completely deleting all packaged and environments of conda. But no help.
Below is some relevant information that might help debug this issue:
$ conda --version
conda 24.5.0

$ nvidia-smi
Sat Oct 19 02:12:06 2024       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 550.90.07              Driver Version: 550.90.07      CUDA Version: 12.4     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                        User-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA RTX 2000 Ada Gene...    Off |   00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   48C    P0            588W /   35W |       8MiB /   8188MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1859      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                              4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

$ which nvidia-smi
/usr/bin/nvidia-smi

Note that my machine runs NVIDIA RTX 2000 Ada Generation. Also above nvidia-smi command says I am running CUDA 12.4. This driver I have installed manually long back when I did not have conda installed on the machine.
I tried setting CUDA_HOME path to my conda environment, but no help:
$ export CUDA_HOME=$CONDA_PREFIX

$ echo $CUDA_HOME
/home/User-M/miniconda3/envs/FairMOT_py38_torch241_CUDA118

$ which nvidia-smi
/usr/bin/nvidia-smi

$ nvcc
Command 'nvcc' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit


no, the conda commands you ran do not install nvcc.  You can find other similar questions here, with a bit of searching.  I did a google search on "conda install nvcc" and this was the first hit.

ehh seems done. I run conda install nvidia/label/cuda-11.8.0::cuda-nvcc from the page you provided. Now my doubt is what conda command actually did ? Only installed pytorch packages compatible with cuda 11.8? (It seem to have downloaded pytorch/linux-64::pytorch-2.4.1-py3.8_cuda11.8_cudnn9.1.0_0 which is of approx 1.5 GB)

I'm not really sure what "ehh seems done" means, or what you are asking exactly.  The initial conda install command you ran primarily installs necessary runtime libraries from the CUDA toolkit, that are needed to make CUDA-accelerated pytorch functional.   I don't have a full manifest for you. nvcc is not needed for basic pytorch functionality.  Again, this topic has been mentioned in a number of places.  I probably won't be able to help further.  Good luck!
